# AWS VPC CIDR and its subnets calculation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, subnet

I have a AWS VPC with CIDR 192.168.0.0/16. I want to create a new VPC with a CIDR which does not overlap with my first VPC.

- What CIDR can I use for my second VPC?
- Now I have to create 4 subnets from this CIDR, which will work fine and will not overlap each other and which fit in the subnet mask of my CIDR.
- Can anyone help me in telling which CIDR and which 4 subnets I can use?

Comment: It seems to be that your second VPC's CIDR fully overlapps with the first one. Why did not chose such "unusual" CIDRs?

Comment: @Marcin oh okay thank u.. then which other VPC CIDR should I use? can u suggest with it 4 subnets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending upon the size you want for each subnet, a traditional way is to use a `/24` range to divide the network, such as:

- VPC: `10.0.0.0/16`
- Subnet 1: `10.0.0.0/24`
- Subnet 2: `10.0.1.0/24`
- Subnet 3: `10.0.2.0/24`
- Subnet 4: `10.0.3.0/24`

Or:

- VPC: `192.168.0.0/16`
- Subnet 1: `192.168.0.0/24`
- Subnet 2: `192.168.1.0/24`
- Subnet 3: `192.168.2.0/24`
- Subnet 4: `192.168.3.0/24`

Of course, you can have the subnets use a small or a bigger range, as desired.

It's generally a good idea to use a [CIDR calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.0.0.0&mask1=16&mask2=) to determine subnets.

Comment: thank u.. then which other VPC CIDR should I use? can u suggest with it 4 subnets?

Comment: I provided it in my answer.

Comment: thank you.. but I am still not sure how to calculate which CIDR to choose and which is also in private range.

Comment: All of the above are CIDRs and they are all in the private IP address range. I have provided a recommended CIDR for the VPC, and CIDRs for each subnet. Could you please explain further what difficulty you are having?

Comment: doesn't 10.0.0.0/16 overlap 192.168.0.0/16?

Comment: A CIDR of `10.0.0.0/16` includes all IP addresses that start with `10.0.x.x`.  A CIDR of `192.168.0.0/16` includes all IP addresses that start with `192.168.x.x`. They do _not_ overlap.

Comment: I see that you have updated your Question to correct the CIDR. I have updated my Answer to match.

Comment: thank u so much! Just a quick question: I can use these subnets for both public and private subnets right? I will be using 2 for public and 2 for private.

Comment: Correct. The CIDR doesn't matter for public/private. To make a public subnet, the associated Route Table should point to an Internet Gateway. That's what makes it publicly accessible.